# Connecting Apache Superset With SQLite

Tags: sqlite, apache-superset

I followed the steps from the [Tutorial - Creating your first dashboard on the Apache Superset docs](https://superset.incubator.apache.org/tutorial.html) to connect Apache Superset with SQLite. When I click the **"Test Connection"** button I get the popup that says:

> "Seems OK!"

But when I am trying to add a table in the next step, I get the following error message:

> "Table [TableName.db] could not be found, please double check your
>   database connection, schema, and table name"

So I know that the connection works and I know that the table name is written correctly. But how do I get the schema from my SQLite Database file that I can paste in the required field?

[image: I marked the schema field with a red border.]

Answer (score -1):

You can go to SQLLab Menu on Superset and on the SQL editor choose your SQLLite database and the schema dropdown will list down all the schema names for you to choose from. Using this approach you can find the right schema for your table name

[SQLLab under Superset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSW7H.png)